# SyntaxError dict[0] not in list, but dict[0] in list works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

first of all iam using python3.5

I gotta do some compare files and write specific lines stuff and now got stuck at a problem.

I have a list of markers wich specify the line of a file a lets be it

```
a = ["bla", "blub"]
```

and for the second file a dict of the marker and the corresponding line.

```
b = {"bla" : "1", "blub" : "2", "nope" : "3"}
```

So if i do now

```
for b[0] in a:
    print(b[b[0]])
```

i get

```
1
2
```

like i want it but no in another i case i wanted to do

```
for b[0] not in a:
    print(b[b[0]])
```

and i get SyntaxError for the not.
Can someone explain me why this is not working and maybe find a way to print all the values for the keys that are not appering in a?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a `for` loop, `in` is a keyword, not the operator. You can't use `not in` for iteration.

Comment: `b[0]` can't work, because `b` doesn't have a key `0`.

Comment: Besides, there is an *infinite* number of values that *aren't* in `a`; which ones would `b[0]` be set to, and in what order?

Comment: The `for b[0] not in a:` line is simply a typo here. You wanted to use `if`, not `for`.

Comment: It's also highly unlikely that you want to change the value of `b[0]` on every iteration, which is what would happen if `b[0]` were valid. `for` loops are a kind of assignment statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Wasnt aware of the keyword/operator difference in a for loop for in. Just one month in to programming feeling kinda stupid now:D but lesson learned, guess i was blinded by the perfectly doing what i want first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the logic completely as others are mentioning. To get the value of the key in the dict that's not present in the list, you can do something like:

```
b = {"bla" : "1", "blub" : "2", "nope" : "3"}
a = ["bla", "blub"]

for x in b.keys():
  if x not in a:
    print(b[x])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot works like a charm. Although i still dont understand why the first without the not works. Since it kinda gives me the output i want in less then a second i kinda want to keep it although i guess i will also do it with an if in although its much slower.

Comment: i guess its taking b[0] as an x just i guess:D